# android check if "Allow sound" notification setting is enabled programmatically

Tags: java, android, notifications, settings

I am really surprised this question as not been asked yet on SO. It's 2020 people. Our application is trying to gather notification manager information from the phone such as, if notifications are enabled and if sounds are enabled. Notifications enabled was easy: `NotificationManager.areNotificationEnabled`, but how do I programmatically check if the `Allow sound` toggle of the App Notification settings is enabled for our application, as depicted in the following screenshot?

[image: settings]

Comment: @sashabeliy that thread is asking how to launch the notification settings activity not get the settings themselves programmatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that you can determine this boolean value by checking if the importance value of the notification manager is less than `0`, i.e. is negative, or is greater than or equal to [`NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT):

```java
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int importance = manager.getImportance();
boolean soundAllowed = importance < 0 || importance >= NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: I want to check in Xiaomi mobiles and used your snippets but every time I am getting true value of soundAllowed. What could be reason for that?

Comment: @Nil what is the value you get for `manager.getImportance()`? Also, what version of AndroidOS are you running?

Comment: -1000 and I checked on android oreo and also checked in android 10.

Comment: Did you find out the solution @NoodleOfDeath ? I also encounter this too in Xiaomi devices..

Comment: This answer doesn't work, at least on Android 10 and MIUI 12.