# android check if "Allow sound" notification setting is enabled or disable programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

So I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669451/android-check-if-allow-sound-notification-setting-is-enabled-programmatically) to solve my problem. but i think the answer is out dated. the code is not working.

```
int importance = manager.getImportance();
boolean soundAllowed = importance < 0 || importance >= NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
```

so this is condition i'm currently using to detect if sound of notification is on or off **(where manager is object of NotificationManager class)**. but it's not working.

i want to check if sound of notification is on or off. if it is off then notify user to turn it on.

thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

In your below code if user has not specified anything for notification or if he has Higher notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise and peeks.  Then your soundAllowed is true.
I think you should remove importance < 0 so you will get this soundAllowed variable only true with user has gave higher importance to notification sounds

```
boolean soundAllowed = importance < 0 || importance >= NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT; // where default value is 3
```

Please check the values here for more clarity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_NONE

Comment: removing importance < 0 gives me false even if sound is on. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED importance is -1000

Comment: importance < 0 means user has not specified anything for the sound.

Comment: but i get value of importance is -1000 even if sound of notification in on. importance of notification channel is 4 which is IMPORTANCE_HIGH